# Find if any object having value in Dictnary<string, list<object>> using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Location>> Locations { get; set; }
```

In location object, one key is `is_update`

I need to find if any of `is_upate` true from dictionary?

I am new in C# and did not find relevant solution for this. Any help appriciated.

Comment: `var didIFindOne = Locations.Any(z => z.Value.Any( y => y.is_upate));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq nested list expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144495/linq-nested-list-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution posted by [@mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208414/find-if-any-object-having-value-in-dictnarystring-listobject-using-linq#comment117053399_66208414) worked for me

```
var didIFindOne = Locations.Any(z => z.Value.Any( y => y.is_upate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

```cs
Locations.Values.Any(l => l.Any(x => x.is_update))
```

Or

```cs
Locations.Values.SelectMany().Any(x => x.is_update)
```